# is there a notification when "slide to unlock" has occurred

Tags: iphone, unlock

I have an iphone game that plays background music using AVSoundPlayer - when someone locks the iphone the music stops which is fine.  But when someone unlocks it, I don't want my music to start playing again while you're staring at the "slide to unlock" screen - I want it to start playing once you've actually slid the button and the app is visible again - is there some way to detect this?  (I've tried  applicationDidBecomeActive but that fires when the phone is unlocked but not when your app is visible yet...)

Answer (score 0):

You could try viewWillAppear.

Comment: viewWillAppear unfortunately does not get called since my application technically was still running the whole time...

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

This sent when your app becomes active

Another answer on SO applicable to your question:

[applicationWillTerminate works as long as I don't switch off the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704789/applicationwillterminate-works-as-long-as-i-dont-switch-off-the-iphone/716912#716912)

Comment: again, applicationDidBecomeActive is called when the user presses the lock/unlock button, but I want to know when the user actually gets rid of the "slide to unlock" screen itself..

Comment: I don't think your application becoming active on the touch of the unlock button, even if you don't slide to unlock, is expected behavior. If that is indeed what you are experiencing, I would file a bug. Obviously, if the phone is still locked your app shouldn't be notified that it has become active.