# UILocalNotification alertLaunchImage doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios4, uilocalnotification, lockscreen

I'm trying to set the `alertLaunchImage` property of `UILocalNotification` to `@"Default.png"`. It works only when the application returns from background, but not when the application returns from lock screen. What might be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: When your app come from background, Do your application launch again ?

Comment: No, it's voip application, so it works in the background. BUT, when it comes from background back it shows this image for a moment. This doesn't happen when it comes back from sleep.

Comment: I think @Black Frog is aware with this behavior of iOS, Anyway i find the one more thread on SO, might be useful for you , just have a look.            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008595/is-there-a-notification-when-slide-to-unlock-has-occurred

Answer (score -2):

The `alertLaunchImage` is used to display a temporary launch image.  Let's say your app has more than one views.

- MainWindow
- AlarmView
- CalendarView
- SettingsView

For our example app, let say I set a `UILocalNotificatiion` for an alarm.  If I set the `alertLaunchImage` to a blank AlarmView.png it won't flicker when I take the user directly to the AlarmView to show them the detail.

Comment: My question was about alertLaunchImage. From the lock screen you can get to the application by simply moving the "Slide to unlock..." control

Comment: That's what is my intention too, I want to show a splash screen before showing the modal view controller on UILocalNotification, but it shows first a cached image of previous application state. In case of background it shows this alertLaunchImage for a moment and then cached screenshot of what was on the screen before the application went to background